# Series derivation

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hi I would like to understand the following equality:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x\frac{d}{dx}x^n\tag{step 1}$$
$$=x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\tag{step 2}$$
$$=x\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x}\tag{step 3}$$
$$=x\frac{-1}{\left(1-x\right)^2}\left(-1\right)\tag{step 4}$$
$$=\frac{x}{\left(1-x\right)^2}$$

Could anybody explain me step 4 ?

Comment: The chain rule.

Comment: Step $4$ is simply taking the derivative of the function $\frac1{1-x}$ with respect to $x$. Writing the function as $(1-x)^{-1}$ may make this more apparent.

Comment: This is just the quotient rule and the chain rule for differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

This is the chain rule applied when differentiating $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

You can add a middle step:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x} =\frac{-1}{(1-x)^2}\frac{d}{dx}(1-x) = \frac{-1}{(1-x)^2} (-1)$$